# Check if a file is being written using Win32 API or C/C++. I do not have write access myself

Tags: c, windows, file, winapi, visual-c++

Inside a Windows C/C++ programm, I need to process a text file. So I just need to open the file for reading. However, I do not want to do that while the file is still being written to by another process. I also know that this other process will eventually close the file and never write to it agin.

Looking at similar questions on stackoverflow, the typical answer is "try and open the file for writing - if that fails then try again later").

Now in this case, my process does not have write access to the file at all. So checking if the file can be opened for writing is not an option . It will always fail irrespective of any other process having write access or not.

Comment: You just need to specify the file sharing explicitly.  If you use CreateFile() then pass 0 for the dwShareMode argument to get exclusive access.  If you use _fsopen() then pass _SH_DENYRW.  If you use a legacy C function like fopen() then stop using it since it is inept at the job.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for your answer, which I will probably employ in my code! However, I am a bit bothered by the fact that your suggestion yields the wrong result if some some other process is just reading the file. Also, employing this test will prevent other processes from reading the file. The latter is just a minor hiccup though, since I would immediately call `CloseHandle()` after `CreateFile()`.  But  I'd still be interested in a less intrusive test

Comment: @HansPassant: Sorry, I just implemented your suggestion, but it does not appear to work: If one process has write access, it is still possible for another process to `CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ, 0 /*dwShareMode*/, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, ...)`. Strange!

Comment: Can't reproduce. If I `CreateFile` first with `GENERIC_WRITE` and even the most permissive sharing mode of `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE`, and then try to `CreateFile` again with `GENERIC_READ` and `0` for sharing mode, the second call fails.

Comment: @HansPassant,Igor Tandetnik: terribly sorry! In my hacked prototype I checked the return values of `CreateFile()` against 0 instead of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. So the suggestion DOES work! However, I would still love to see a solution that just rules out a writer, but allows readers.

Comment: Just pass `GENERIC_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_READ`. Note that many writers don't use `FILE_SHARE_READ` and so deny `GENERIC_READ` access to other processes regardless of whether they use `FILE_SHARE_READ` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant and Igor Tandetnik said you just need to pass the appropriate sharing flag to `CreateFile`. As the MSDN documentation for [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx#FILE_SHARE_WRITE) says:

> `FILE_SHARE_WRITE 0x00000002`
>
> Enables subsequent open operations on a file or device to request write access.
>
> Otherwise, other processes cannot open the file or device if they request write access.
>
> **If this flag is not specified, but the file or device has been opened for write access
>   or has a file mapping with write access, the function fails.**

You'll want to use code like the following:

```
HANDLE handle = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
                           OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    DWORD errcode = GetLastError();
    if (errcode == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION) {
        printf("%s: sharing violation\n", name);
    } else {
        printf("%s: CreateFile failed, error code = %lu\n", name, errcode);
    }
} else {
    printf("%s: CreateFile succeeded\n", name);
}
```

This code in unable to tell if the `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` occurred because the other process has the file open for writing or because the another process didn't use `FILE_SHARE_READ` when opening the file. In the later case any attempt to read from the file will fail with a sharing violation. The `FILE_SHARE_READ` flag is passed to prevent sharing violations in the case when the file already been opened and `FILE_SHARE_READ` was used. You could also add `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` but I assume you'd consider that the same as write access.

Comment: Just tried your solution, but doesn't appear to work: since CreateFile() with dsDesiredAccess set to 0 always succeeds.

Comment: I was assuming that the writing processed has called: `CreateFileA(name, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)`. Then running your code with `dwDesiredAccess = 0` erroneously returns a valid handle. Setting `dwDesiredAccess = GENERIC_READ` and `dwShareMode = 0` (Hans' suggestion) works. But the latter gives false positives when another process has obtained read access via `::CreateFileA(name, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);`

Comment: So pass `GENERIC_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_READ` in your `CreateFile` call.

Comment: I've updated my example to use both `GENERIC_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_READ`.